# What's the proper term for accepting mixed variables?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to look up best practices and techniques for functions that accept "mixed" variables. This is similar to how the jQuery object accepts string, objects, and HTML Elements, and intelligently figures out what to do.

But I'm not sure what this pattern is called. How would a knowledgeable JavaScript developer refer to this technique?

For example:

```
function formatParams(mixed) {
    var params = {};
    switch (typeof mixed) {
        case 'string' :
            params = {query: mixed};
            break;
        case 'number' :
            params = {id: mixed};
            break;
        case 'function' :
            params = {callback: mixed}
            break;
        default: 
            params = mixed;
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: I *think* it's called "overloading", but I could be way off XD

Comment: @Kolink: Overloading is when you define the same method several times with different signatures (i.e. different types). But JavaScript doesn't have type-hinting, so overloading isn't possible here.

Comment: It's seems to be some kind of polymorphism/function overloading. But it's not a feature of the language (such as Java has), rather a consequence of dynamic typing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question makes much sense in the context of a weakly typed language.. It's just type checking?

Comment: This is overloading. This is how it is done in a dynamic language. @Kolink is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a name for this pattern, but I guess "quasi-overloading via polymorphic parameters" might be one way to describe it. It isn't *true* polymorphism or overloading (hence the qualifier "quasi"), but more a consequence of JavaScript having dynamic typing.

We're probably going off into "subjective" territory here, but I'm typically not a fan of "mixed" parameters because that leads to ambiguity and possible logic-bombs when you're handling parameters (basically a huge and unwieldy `switch-case` or `if-else` where you try to handle different combinations of parameters).

I prefer using named parameters (or at least the flavor that JavaScript allows) through an object literal:

```
formatParams({
    stringParam: "string",
    numberParam: 42,
    booleanParam: true,
    functionParam: function() {
        ..
    }
});
```

Then inside the actual function, you can check for the existence of each, individual parameter, and make sure that it is of the right type:

```
function formatParams(options) {
    if(typeof options.stringParam !== "undefined" && typeof options.stringParam === "string") {
        //do what it is you want
    } else {
        throw "stringParam is expected to be of type 'string'.";
    }

    //and so on...
}
```

I find this form of parameter-handling to be less error-prone and it is easier to perform type-checking and also to see if they provided all the parameters required.

Comment: That's my preferred method if I'm taking in multiple arguments, but I love the shortcut elegance of "polymorphic parameters" when I only need one argument. i.e. find(2) and find('foo') versus find({id:2) and find({queryTerm:'foo'}). Thanks for your thoughtful response!

Comment: @elstgav Personally I'd prefer to have `findById`, `findByQuery`, `findByCallback` and so on, akin to `getElementById`, `getElementsByTagName` and so on. Even if they then go on to call a single `find` function with the appropriately formatted parameter, it's easier on the front-end.